# the database environment has all of the following component except :- user or separate files

Tags: database, relational-database

I found this question in many sites with different answers, some says user is not the part of the db environment and other says separate files. But I don't any explanation about it. Which one is correct and why. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The database environment has all of the following component except :- 1)user or 2)separate files

Answer (score 0):

Ans: Separate Files

As database does not exists without user. To login or connect a database, user is required, which can even be a admin user.